# Eclipse marketplace statistics (Installs, Clickthroughs, Errors)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

> [**disclaimer**] Since the question was raised:  The question is not about
>   a company. The Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC) is open source and
>   part of all Eclipse IDE packages. The Eclipse Marketplace is for the
>   Eclipse IDE what Maven Central is for Maven (for those who don't know
>   it, it's just a website) (Thanks howlger for pointing that out) [/**disclaimer**]

There is a [statistics](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic#group-metrics-tab) section for every plugin in the eclipse marketplace but I wonder how the numbers are collected and submitted. I searched around but the only thing I could find was a [bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509063) which seems to address some aspects.

My questions are of **general** nature, the mentioned plugin is just an **example**:

1. How the numbers are submitted / counted (especially **Installs**)?
2. What does `Clickthroughs` exactly mean? (clickthroughs the webpage or the installer ...?)
3. Until recently the plugin link was broken and every installation failed with several error messages and nobody could install it. Why isn't that reflected in the [error](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic#undefined) section and the error [report](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/unsuccessful/installs/1976579/error_report.csv)?

I successfully installed the [plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic#group-metrics-tab) however the number of `Installs` did not increase. Is it just a update-timing issue or does e.g. my proxy blocks something? Or does the maintainer need to enable/activate something in the marketplace settings?

Screenshot of eclipse marketplace client (MPC) which is part of every eclipse installation. All mentioned plugins are just examples which should help to illustrate the issue.
[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Comment: What company do you mean? There is no company. I am interessted in the general statistic mechanism. The plugin is just an example.

Comment: shouldnt you be asking eclipse devs?

Comment: Yes and No. Everybody with that knowledge can answer. This I don't get. Many questions asked here are about certain open source libraries or tools. I mean there are eclipse, eclipse-plugin and even eclipse-marketplace tags available. So why can't I ask a question about eclipse?

Comment: @Lonzak: Your question is off-topic, because it is not about programming or the use of a development tool. Your question is about some organization's homepage and how the content is calculated. You should ask Eclipse.

Comment: The numbers are also shown within eclipse. But you are right in that way that it is not a pure question about programming. It is more how the technique behind eclipse marketplace works. Still think it is a pity why this question can't be asked on SO.

Comment: because even if someone from eclipse were to answer _here_, there is no way to maintain this Q&A for SO community.Read the link in my first comment

Comment: Why is that? (There are certainly many eclipse developers here - i'm quite certain of that. The question gets answered and everybody sees it/ knows it. Can you explain the maintenance aspect?)

Comment: because its the company's internal working and may change later. there is no way for anyone who comes across this to know if it is correct. If you have any issues I suggest you take it up in meta..

Comment: Yeah but any question about any open source programming library which is answered here may change in future since those libs will get updated. I read the link however my question is quite different imho. It is not about personal issues but a general questions about a technique used by eclipse...

Comment: Please read the linked post and if you still have any issue you can post in meta

Comment: @SurajRao Your link does not apply here because the question is not about a company. The Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC) is open source and part of all [Eclipse IDE packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/). The Eclipse Marketplace is for the Eclipse IDE what Maven Central is for Maven (for those who don't know it, it's just a website).

Comment: @howlger fair enough.. retracted my cv

Comment: If you want to take a look at the [code of the Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC), here it is](http://git.eclipse.org/c/mpc/org.eclipse.epp.mpc.git). No, the maintainer does not need to enable/activate something. I guess the installs number is only an update-timing issue (at Eclipse load balancers are used to handle the [heavy traffic](http://status.eclipse.org/)). According to my understanding, _Clickthroughs_ are the number of times that details about this item were requested (via MPC or via a web browser).

Comment: You've mentioned that the code which is doing what you're interested in is open-source. If it's open source, why have you not just gone and *looked in the code* to figure out what is being done? Are you actually trying to ask "why is it done this way?" It sounds like you're saying something along the lines of "Hey, there's some code over here that's doing something, but I'm too lazy to even go look at it myself and *try* to figure it out. To answer my question, go look at that code and explain to me what it's really doing for this list of things."

Comment: @Makyen Who are you addressing? howlger or me?

Comment: @Mayken There's really no need for the "...but I'm too lazy..." comment.

Comment: @skomisa I agree. But maybe Makyen doesn't know the whole background of the story. The above clarification (open source product and so on....) was added because some people were thinking that its some proprietary product I was asking about and voting for to 'close' it. Then howlger clarified that. But if it would be this easy to just look it up and understand everything then most of the questions posted here would be superfluous.